# How to do syntax highlighting of methods in vs code (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, methods, themes

When I set up the theme in vs code I chose "Monokai Dark Soda", but the problem is that it doesn't highlight methods in a separate color (just white). I tried to solve it in the `settings.json`
file and used the following code:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.method",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#66D9EF",
            }
        },

        {
            "scope": "entity.name.function.member",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#66D9EF",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Dark Soda]": {
        "rules": {
            "method": "#66D9EF"
        }
    }
}
```

But none of these solutions work either together or separately, although in all other respects, customization works fine. At the same time, choosing from ready-made themes in the market, the methods are highlighted in a separate color, that is, it is possible to implement. But for some reason I can't.

How i want:
[with method highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOtvG.png)

How it works:
[without method highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lEEN.png)

Comment: You do have the Python extension installed right? (the official one by Microsoft) Dumb question, but just checking.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2768) help at all? Not making it an answer because I'm not sure if it'll help.

Comment: @Cyb3rst0rm Thank you so much. I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days and you helped me a lot. Your link was not an answer, but prompted me to the right thoughts and I wrote the solution in the answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the "MagicPython" module is used for python syntax highlighting in vs code. To highlight methods, you should update this module in the store (just in case) and add the following code to `settings.json`:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.function-call.generic",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "YOUR_COLOR" // choose your color
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This will also colorize any callable object (with "( )" ) and functions in particular, but I didn't find a separate solution for methods in the scopes list.

If this solution did not help you or you want to configure it yourself, then here is a link to the official MagicPython repository with all scopes: [MagicPython scopes](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/blob/master/misc/scopes)